# Black holes analogies in Yang-Mills theory

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, yang-mills

Theory of gravity is very similar to Yang-Mills theory.

In General relativity there are black holes. Is some analogies of black holes in Yang-Mills theory?

Comment: It's not similar. General relativity and Yang Mills theory come from completely different gauge groups.

Comment: @RyanParikh This is not entirely correct. GR is indeed a gauge theory, it's just not quite a Yang-Mills theory. There are still some similarities. In particular, black holes share some similarities with instantons. The difference is that instantons are defined to minimize the Euclidean action while blackholes minimize the Lorentzian action.

Comment: @RichardMyers What do you mean when you say Euclidean action and Lorentzian action?

Comment: @RyanParikh These actions are related by a Wick transformation.

Comment: @RyanParikh instantons are the solutions of the (anti-)self-duality equaiton. But in the Minkowski space, the hodge duality comes with an imaginary unit, so one will have $F = \pm i \star F$. So, there are no real solutions. On the contrary, on Euclidean space there are indeed real solutions, as well as in gravity  - this subject is called self-dual gravity, the fields with weyl tensor of definite chirality. However, in the other direction, I am not aware, whether there is analgoue of black holes in Minkowski space

Comment: See also Yang–Mills black holes in quasitopological gravity, https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-09241-2

Answer (score 5):

There is a recently discovered correspondence between gauge theory and gravity called the *double copy*, which relates two distinct non-abelian Yang–Mills theories and gravity. Informally, gravity theory can be seen as a “product” of sorts of two gauge theories:
$$ \text{gravity} = \text{gauge} \times \text{gauge}.$$
Originally this correspondence has been formulated at the level of quantum scattering amplitudes but since then it has been extended to include maps relating classical solutions in gauge theories and  in gravity, the so-called *classical double copy*. For now, this classical correspondence has been established for configurations that linearize the field equations. At the gravity side this include Kerr–Schild metrics:
$$
 g_{μν} = \eta_{μν} + \phi(x) k_μ k_ν,
$$
where $η_{μν}$ is Minkowski spacetime metric, $ϕ$ is the scalar field and $k_μ$ is the null vector field.
At the Yang–Mills side of the correspondence the gauge field would be:
$$
A^{a}_μ = c^a \phi(x) k_μ,
$$
where $c^{a}$ is the color factor while $\phi$ and $k_\mu$ are taken from gravity side.

Since Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics could be written in Kerr–Schild form, this correspondence would be enough to write down the gauge field analogues of static and rotating black holes. For Schwarzschild metric the gauge side is simply the Coulomb field of a color charge. For Kerr black hole the gauge field is sourced by a rotating color charged disk and away from it contains both Coulomb term and magnetic dipole term. A metric with a NUT parameter corresponds to a dyon. Higher dimensional generalizations are also available. All of these examples are *Abelian-like* (essentially Maxwell fields) in character, though it is conjectured that the correspondence extends to full nonlinear theories.

**References**

For a pedagogical introduction to the topic:

- White, C. D. (2018). *The double copy: gravity from gluons*. Contemporary Physics, 59(2), 109-125, [arXiv:1708.07056](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07056).

For more details about black hole analogues in gauge theories:

- Monteiro, R., O’Connell, D., & White, C. D. (2014). *Black holes and the double copy*. Journal of High Energy Physics, 2014(12), 56, [doi:10.1007/JHEP12(2014)056](https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP12(2014)056), [arXiv:1410.0239](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.0239).